# How to get number FDs occupied by a processes without using losf?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rhel

I am trying to get number of FDs occupied by my processes , i tried with lsof , unfortunately it is taking too much of time  . If there any other way to get this number , i also tried looking at /proc//fd , but didn't find what i am looking for.

Comment: Uh... if you didn't find what you're looking for in there, then just what *are* you looking for?

Comment: thanks for pointing out , i got some documentation which explains ho to comprehend that files,
/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<fd> - Information about opened file(source : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)